# Java. Вопрос о скорости

Tags: java, json

Много где вижу, что JSON данные превращают в объект, например есть 
`JSONArray = [{"id":1,"name":"Anton"},{"id":2,"name":"Alex"},{"id":3,"name":"Pavel"}]`

и для этого делают класс

```
class User {
   String name;
   int id;

   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setId(int _id) {
       id = _id;
   }

   public void setName(String _name) {
       name = _name;
   }
}
```

Потом код примерно такой:

```
List<User> users = getUsers();
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
     User user = users.get(i);
     holder.name.setText(user.getName());
}
```

И вопрос, так быстрее? Или удобней? Почему бы сразу не использовать такой код:

```
JSONArray users = getUsers();
for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
     try {
         JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(i);
         holder.name.setText(user.getString("name"));
     } (JSONException ignore) { } 
}
```

Есть вообще какая то разница в скорости выполнения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне лично нравится первый подход.

плюсы за первый

- компактней код (а лишний класс пусть себе где то болтается)
- меньше шансов на ошибку, компилятор подскажет (например, вместо `user.getString("name")` легко можно написать `user.getString("nane")` и потом ломать голову над ошибкой.
- если поменяется структура json (всякое бывает), то лучше обнаружить это ещё на этапе загрузки json, чем в файле, который отдали заказчику.
- только класс, который делает загрузку, знает о json. Другим не нужно переживать о структуре данных.
- если завтра решат использовать yaml или xml, то нужно будет переделать только в одном месте.
- Также завтра може оказаться, что в библиотеке для парсинга json решили поменять методы, так как `getString` не такой красивый как `getValueAsString` или что то в этом духе (у меня лично была ситуация, когда в новой версии библиотеки решили обновить одно имя, добавивь забытую s).

плюсы второго подхода:

- легко быстро накостылять код
- ваш код потом вряли украдут, а если украдут, то будут плеваться и не будут использовать.

  - не нужно делать "якобы ненужные классы"

А скорость... а кто переживает о скорости в java? О скорости нужно переживать алгоритмически.

Comment: Очень многие переживают о скорости в Java. Банковские операции, HFT, BigData, можно продолжать очень долго этот список. Просто этот пример - не тот случай.

Comment: переживать о скорости в java - это как выбрать бронированный (потому что как java безопасный) автомобиль и переживать, что он не ездит быстро (как с/с++).

Comment: зря вы так. jit-компиляция, хорошие оптимизаторы в HotSpot позволяют добиться скорости сопоставимой с с/с++. зато шансов выстрелить себе в ногу гораздо меньше

Comment: да, позволяет. И в большинстве случаев скорости достаточно. Более того, хороший код на java обгонит плохой код на плюсах. Но в общем на с++ всегда можно написать код, который будет быстрее java.

Comment: а на ассемблере еще быстрее можно написать =) речь не о том, что можно, а что нельзя. а о том, что есть люди, которые переживают о скорости в Java. те же перформансники из Oracle не зря свой хлеб едят

Comment: А вот по поводу ассемблера я не был бы столь уверен. Я думаю, что сейчас почти нет таких людей, которые помнят как спариваются различные инструкции и умеют их правильно переставлять (и делать это лучше компилятора).

Главная проблема скорости в java на данный момент - это GC. И это jit никак не исправит. Да, есть подвижки в сторону его улучшения, но.. Но это тема отдельного большого холивара.

Answer (score 1):

В скорости выполнения разницы нет. По крайней мере на том уровне, о котором можно беспокоиться (пару микросекунд не в счет).
Первый код смотрится компактнее, с ним меньше шансов допустить ошибку (приведение типов, неправильное имя поля).
С другой стороны, если у вас это будет использоваться только в одном месте, то можно и "костыли" из второго примера оставить. Но как только это появится еще где-то пару раз, то тут стоит задуматься и привести весь код к единой концепции, как это в первом примере.